# Обычный (a href=''/'') и уже работает некорректно в IE! Есть ли выход?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, explorer, css

Доброго всем кодинга.
Делаю один прожектик, и как бы некоторые индивидуумы просят, что бы прожект работал и на всеми Любимом Internet Explorer'е. Всё в нём как бы работает, но вот мелочи...
Простая кнопка **назад**, реализованная DIV'ом и a href'ом уже не желает работать.
[Пример моей кнопки назад](http://jsfiddle.net/3v8zZ/3/), которая во всех бродилках работает на ура, но, кроме IE (IE у меня 8-ой). Попробуйте этот пример в IE.

Даже [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) не желает отображать ни себя, ни тем более кнопку мою нормально в этом чудном браузере.
Или выход один. Старая добрая картинка кнопки? Но это же шаг в прошлое.

Comment: Замените использование <a> на стили css: cursor: pointer; и обработку псевдоклассов :hover и :focus

Comment: действительно, чойта это она не работает?

    <input type='button' value='Назад' style='
    ...
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff6d6d', endColorstr='#cc0000',GradientType=0 );
  
    border-radius: 5px;'>

Свойство `style` кончается на следуещем апострофе, как раз там, где описывается правило для msie. Еще один гвоздь в крышку гроба инлайн-стилей. Даже если причина проблемы не в этом.

Answer (score 1):

Голову ломать не стал и повесил JavaScript на клик по (input).

```
onclick='goBack();'
```